# Need help solving this system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

$$\begin{align}
a+2.27 &= \ln(33a-14) * b(33a-15) * (33a-14)^c\\
c+1 &= bc(33a-15)(33a-14)^{c-1} + 33(33a-14)^c\\
d &= (33a-15)(33a-14)^c
\end{align}$$

---

Solve for a in terms of d. Or just establish a relationship between a and d.

---

I need to solve this equation because I was originally trying to optimize a function using Lagrange multipliers. Here are the equations that I narrowed the problem down to. I'm not sure how to solve for it because it's hard to eliminate variables.

Comment: I very much doubt that there is a closed form solution to this highly nonlinear system of equations. Things might look a little better if you let $g = 33a - 14$ since that subexpression appears often.

Comment: You already have $d$ expressed in terms of $a$.

Comment: But I need to eliminate the c variable.